# I'm trying to add style properties within <style> tags, but it just shows up as text on my page

Tags: html, styles

I'm trying to add style properties within `<style>` tags, but it just shows up as text on my page. I'm using brackets and it usually picks up the style properties so I'm assuming my code is wrong.

```
<style> body {background-image: url(pix/background.gif); } </style>
```

Comment: adding type="text/css" to the style tag may make a difference  <style type="text/css"></style>

Comment: Are you attempting to add it in the body or the header? Placing it in the body may cause it to appear as text on your page. Style tags should go in between the `head` tags near the top of your html code.

Comment: If you're using Adobe Brackets please update your tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `<style></style>` tag to the HTML page's header, between the head tags

```
<head> 
<style> 
body {background-image: url(pix/background.gif); } 
</style>
</head>
```

if htat doesnt work, verify your file encoding, and make sure it is UTF8 to get more compatible with browsers.